# Not able to proceed because of #opc issue in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, url, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am facing one issue while running my selenium scripts.
I am automating an eCommerce website and not able to checkout because of below issue.

- I have added a product into the cart and trying to checkout,but after clicking on checkout button selenium is not able to go to the next page.
- When i try manually or in other system is working perfectly fine.

The difference i have noticed is that when selenium clicks on checkout button it goes to

> "https://checkout.primaryarms.com/sca-dev-montblanc/checkout.ssp?_ga=1.1522549.51964357.1482315015&is=checkout&lang=en_US"

if I run the same script in other system it goes to 
"

> https://checkout.primaryarms.com/sca-dev-montblanc/checkout.ssp?_ga=1.1522549.51964357.1482315015&is=checkout&lang=en_US#opc"

The difference is second url has extra text **#opc** added, which is not coming in my case   . I am not sure how to resolve this problem.

does anyone have the answer?

Comment: Show code sample you use to click the button

Comment: Show HTML and code